# SSIS : Generic "Derived Column" and "RecordSet Destination"

Tags: ssis

I would like to know if it's possible to create a generic "Derived Column" and a generic "RecordSet Destination"

I'm trying to collect some info from a log table and send the data to the appropriate recipient.
Depending on the type of errors I will need to collect some fields from the table.
Some of the fields are dates and I would like to work them if I they are collected (Derived Column)
Then, I store them in a "RecordSet Destination" to create a table from it (htm file) and send it by email.

1. So is there a way in "Derived Column" to say if column "X" exists then replace it with (...)?
2. Is there a way to put (*) in a "RecordSet Destination" no matter what we have as fields?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to read out the logfile in a scripting component and have the formatted html email as the output of even send the email already from the scripting component.

Comment: That was my last solution. At work they prefer to avoid using the scripting component as much as we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's no way of avoiding the use of a script. There's not a lot of traffic on this post and I wasn't able to find answers on the net.

I had a script that will adapt to my new needs, I just need to change the way I fill the data table.

```
        public void Main()
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(); 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string tab = "\t";

        oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["DataToSendToIT"].Value);

        sb.AppendLine("<html>");
        sb.AppendLine(tab + "<body>");
        sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "<table>");

        // headers.
        sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("<td bgcolor=#CEC8C5>{0}</td>", dc.ColumnName);
        }

        sb.AppendLine("</tr>");

        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

            i = i + 1;

            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                string cellValue = dr[dc] != null ? dr[dc].ToString() : "";
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("<td bgcolor=#CCEEFF>{0}</td>", cellValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", cellValue);
                }
            }

            sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
        }

        sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "</table>");
        sb.AppendLine(tab + "</body>");
        sb.AppendLine("</html>");


        string currentLogFile = Dts.Variables["ScaleFolderPath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["LogsFolder"].Value.ToString() + "Log " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ".htm";
        File.WriteAllText(currentLogFile, sb.ToString());
        Dts.Variables["CurrentLogFile"].Value = currentLogFile;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```